# Navigating $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$Let's consider a silly-looking question first. Consider $\Z/p\Z$. Say I am allowed the two operations $x\mapsto x+1$ and $x\mapsto 2x$. Then, starting from $0$, I can express every given element $y$ of $\Z/p\Z$ in $O(\log p)$ steps; moreover, I can figure out how to do it in time $O(\log p)$.

The answer is trivial: just lift $y$ to an integer, and express it in base $2$.

Now, what happens if we consider $x\mapsto rx$ instead of $x\mapsto 2x$?

(Assume that $r$ has order at least $\gg\log p$, as otherwise things don't work.)

That is: can one express every given element $y$ of $\Z/p\Z$ in $O(\log p)$ steps by starting from 0 and using the operations $x\mapsto x+1$ and $x\mapsto rx$? If so, can one figure out how to express such an element in that way in $O(\log p)$ (or $O((\log p)^c))$ steps?

Comment: This looks like a case for the sum-product theorem http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/SumProductTheorem.html , but I can't see how to apply it.

Comment: He assumes the order of r is $>> \log p$.

Comment: The sum-product theorem can't tell you *how* to express the element y, as far as I know.

Comment: The sum-product theorem would, however, yield a non-constructive solution if only we were allowed the operations (a) (x,y)->x+y, (b) x->r*x.

Comment: I agree - I don't even see how to get *existence* with the bound $O(\log ^C p)$ at the moment..

Comment: This reminds me a little of obtaining fractions from the usual generators of $SL(2,Z)$ as in Conway's rope game.  That is, represent a rational number $a/b$ as a vector $(a,b)$ and then apply the "add one" matrix (usually denoted $T$) and the "negative reciprocate" matrix (denoted $S$).

So maybe replacing the $S$ matrix by Diag(r,1) one has a similar situation mod $p$.

Comment: Just to clarify: you want the bound to be independent of r, right?

Comment: Yes, I'd like the bound to be independent of r.

In SL(2,Z/pZ), if you have the operations given by the matrices S and T, you do have diameter O(log p) (by Selberg's spectral gap or newer results). I think the problem of providing an algorithm there is quite open, though. 

Do you have a reference for Conway's rope game?

Comment: I guess you exclude the case of $r=p-1$?

Comment: As I said, the order of r is assumed to be >> log p. This excludes r=p-1 immediately.

Comment: I learned Conway's rope game from Conway himself when I was an undergraduate.
Here is a link I found:
http://www.geometer.org/mathcircles/tangle.pdf


Comment: Conway's rope game seems to be a nice way to present SL_2(Z) to kids - but I don't see how it provides any sort of algorithm for anything. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

Let $r$ be the "base" and $x$ the number to represent.

Let $m = \log_{2} (p) + \epsilon$. Construct the matrix $L$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x & \lambda & 0 & & ... & & 0 \\\\
1 & 0 & \lambda & &  & & 0 \\\\
\bar{r} & & & \lambda & & & \\\\
... & & & & & & \\\\
\bar{r^m} & & & & & & \lambda \\\\
p & & & & & & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
where $\bar{r^i}$ is $(r^i \mod p)$.
Given a representation:
$$x = \sum_{i = 0}^{m} a_i r^i (\mod p)$$
or more precisely:
$$x = \sum_{i = 0}^{m} a_i \bar{r^i} - tp$$
where $a_i \in \{0,1\}$, we multiply the matrix from the left by the row:
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & -a_0 & -a_1 & ... & -a_m & t \end{array} \right)$$
and get the short row:
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & \lambda & -a_0 \lambda & -a_1 \lambda & ... & -a_m \lambda \end{array} \right)$$
since we expect the number of non zero $a_i$'s to be around $\log_2(p)/2$, we expect the norm of this row to be:
$$\sqrt{\lambda^2 \sum_{i = 0}^{m} a_i^2} \sim \lambda \sqrt{\log_2(p)/2}$$
Note that:
$$|\det(L)|^{1/(m+3)} = (p \lambda^{m+2})^{1/(m+3)}$$
While we want to keep the row short, we want to make other rows long. So we choose:
$$\lambda \sim p \sqrt{\log_2(p)/2}$$

Going the other way around, applying the LLL algorithm to $L$, for a few small $\epsilon$, should produce a representation.

This algorithm is heuristic and I am not sure how to prove anything stronger. Try looking for papers on the knapsack problem, since it is quite similar.

Comment: I fail to see how this is a probabilistic solution, as opposed to just a heuristic. I may be missing something. 

(Also, how do you do LLL modulo p?)

A probabilistic solution - in the sense of a probabilistic algorithm that would find the solution quickly with probability 1-o(1) for all or almost all elements y - would be very interesting indeed.


Comment: Aha - this looks interesting now. What we have is a knapsack problem where the (absolute values of the) coefficients have to add up to O(log p) and the linear combination must be exactly y. (If this is formulated over the integers, then, as you have pointed out, we can do this simply by using the basis 1,r,r^2,...,r^m,p.) 

This is in general an NP-complete problem, if memory serves me well. The question is whether the fact that our numbers are powers of r helps us any.

Comment: @Helfgott: Maybe. Would be nice. But I wouldn't put money on it.

Comment: It's difficult to see how to make anything out of this, really. Do you think that, say, the methods out there for breaking certain specific knapsack-based cryptographic algorithms could be of any help?

Comment: Algorithmically my answer is pretty sound. I would bet that it does solve many instances (I refrain from saying most since I don't really know). As for knapsack, I only know of the problem and its similarity, nothing on actual solutions.